# Bad practice - generating javascript code for getElementbyID from PHP while loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm creating a html table from a mysql query via PHP. I'm filling every table row with one record from the query's result set.

I use the javascript function `getElementById` to show a dialog or close it.

Since I have many rows, I added the javascript code to the while loop / table data.
This is creating a ton of javacode and I'm very sure this is a good example of bad practice.

How can I do this without generating (programmtically) a unique javascript function for each row? Is an array the way to go?

This is my code

```
<?php while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  $current_row_number++; ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
    <!--Popup Window-->   
    <dialog id="window<?php echo $current_row_number; ?>">  
    <h3>Description</h3>  
    <p><?php echo $r['description']; ?></p>  
    <button id="exit<?php echo $current_row_number; ?>">Close</button>  
    </dialog>  
    <button id="show<?php echo $current_row_number; ?>">View</button> 
    <!--Popup Window-->   
     <script type="text/javascript">

    var dialog<?php echo $current_row_number; ?> = document.getElementById('window<?php echo $current_row_number; ?>');  
    document.getElementById('show<?php echo $current_row_number; ?>').onclick = function() {  dialog<?php echo $current_row_number; ?>.show();   };  
    document.getElementById('exit<?php echo $current_row_number; ?>').onclick = function() {  dialog<?php echo $current_row_number; ?>.close();  };  

     </script>
     </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

generates this example output:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var dialog8 = document.getElementById('window8');  
document.getElementById('show8').onclick = function() {  dialog8.show();   };  
document.getElementById('exit8').onclick = function() {  dialog8.close();  };  
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

var dialog9 = document.getElementById('window9');  
document.getElementById('show9').onclick = function() {  dialog9.show();   };  
document.getElementById('exit9').onclick = function() {  dialog9.close();  };  

 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

var dialog10 = document.getElementById('window10');  
document.getElementById('show10').onclick = function() {  dialog10.show();   };  
document.getElementById('exit10').onclick = function() {  dialog10.close();  };  

 </script>
```

and so on...

I don't need a full example but I would be glad if you can push my in the right direction. I want to get rid of that `$current_row_number`...

Doing repetetive tasks in code is bad practice and the java script code looks very rubbish

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed, there's no need for all of that.

Within an event handler, `this` refers to the element that the event handler was attached to, and the `target` property of the event object tells you where the event started. You can use this information to have a single handler on the table that handles clicks on these buttons. Put a class on the buttons that indicates whether they should "show" or "hide", then do something like this (see comments):

```
document.getElementById("the-table").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // Find the row
    var row = e.target;
    while (row.tagName != "TR") {
        if (row === this) {
            // The click wasn't on a row, ignore it
            return;
        }
        row = row.parentNode;
    }

    // Find the button
    var button = e.target;
    while (button.tagName != "BUTTON") {
        if (button === this) {
            // The click wasn't on a button, ignore it
            return;
        }
        button = button.parentNode;
    }

    // Find the dialog
    var dialog = row.querySelector("dialog");
    if (!dialog) {
        // Couldn't find it
        return;
    }

    // Now, use the `className` or `classList` on `button` to determine
    // whether to show or hide, and do that on `dialog`
}, false);
```

Naturally, you can encapsulate some of that in utility functions (or use a library like jQuery that already has).

Here's a simplified example, using `h3` instead of `dialog`:

```js
document.getElementById("the-table").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // Find the row
  var row = e.target;
  while (row.tagName != "TR") {
    if (row === this) {
      // The click wasn't on a row, ignore it
      return;
    }
    row = row.parentNode;
  }

  // Find the button
  var button = e.target;
  while (button.tagName != "BUTTON") {
    if (button === this) {
      // The click wasn't on a button, ignore it
      return;
    }
    button = button.parentNode;
  }

  // Find the "dialog"
  var dialog = row.querySelector("h3");
  if (!dialog) {
    // Couldn't find it
    return;
  }

  // Now, use the `className` or `classList` on `button` to determine
  // whether to show or hide, and do that on `dialog`
  if (button.className == "show") {
    dialog.className = "";
  } else {
    dialog.className = "hidden";
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="the-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h3 class="hidden">Dialog 1</h3>
        <div>
          <button class="show">Show 1</button>
          <button class="hide">Hide 1</button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h3 class="hidden">Dialog 2</h3>
        <div>
          <button class="show">Show 2</button>
          <button class="hide">Hide 2</button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h3 class="hidden">Dialog 3</h3>
        <div>
          <button class="show">Show 3</button>
          <button class="hide">Hide 3</button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h3 class="hidden">Dialog 4</h3>
        <div>
          <button class="show">Show 4</button>
          <button class="hide">Hide 4</button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```